# how to extract date format from a string date in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose i have a table `test` which has a column `mydate` varchar type and it stores different date formats, below is a sample date format:

[image]

now i want to write a query for above id = 1 which will return me the output like:

> ```
> 1 | d M Y
> ```

So my requirement is to get the date format in the query response like above, understand one more below example

> For Example:

```
I have 12 June 1999 stored in column so expected output:

d M Y
```

I searched alot for this i did not get the answer, i am not getting what to try like

```
select id, ..(main thing that i am not getting)... from test where id = 1
```

please help if any one knows this

Comment: How? Just provide correctly formatted dates. That said, PHP's tools for correctly guessing malformed dates are pretty good

Comment: this is my  Compulsion because this is an old existing database table i can not do any change for this

Comment: In which format you need the date write that format.

Comment: SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(mydate,'%d/%m/%Y') AS formatted_date
FROM test where id = 1
ORDER BY mydate DESC

Comment: @ Kamran Khatti no i want to extract date format from a date

Comment: I can't see how you can differentiate between things like 11 9 2016 and 9 11 2016

Comment: @ Strawberry because i store it like 11 09 2017, it differentiate between these above

Comment: What's the possible data, any combination from here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format?

Comment: Seems like you have to do pattern matching like this, `SELECT id, IF(UPPER(mydate) REGEXP '^[0-9]{2} (JANUARY|FEBRUARY|MARCH|APRIL|MAY|JUNE|JULY|AUGUST|SEPTEMBER|OCTOBER|NOVEMBER|DECEMBER) [0-9]{4}$', 'd M Y', '')
FROM test WHERE id = 1`, but that seems impractical for more than one format.

Comment: @Eggsalad thanks but does not work for my case :(

Comment: @BunkerBoy Do you want output `12 June 1999` with `d M Y` with SQL query?

Comment: @ Sahil Gulati yes i m trying to achieve by query but i thinking i have to change my way for this case, is there any way in php that solve my problem ?

Comment: If you put a space between '@' and the username, then the user isn't notified. Your response to my previous comment makes no sense.

Comment: @ Strawberry you wanted to know how i am differentiating these two dates 11 9 2016 and 9 11 2016 ? am i right ? but i don't have these format in my table, currently i have only this above format 08 June 1990

Answer (score 0):

By using STR_TO_DATE you can achieve this.

> select id,DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d %M %Y'),'%d %M %Y') as date from test

Comment: this is not my requirement, please read carefully my question